# Attaching the debugger to a process doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I've got a C++ application that doesn't quite work right. When I ask VisualStudio to run it, it runs just fine. But when I copy the compiled binary to its final location, it whinges about some sort of permissions problem.

I would dearly love to know exactly where it's getting stuck. According to [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx), it's supposed to be possible to attach the VisualStudio debugger to an arbitrary process. But when I do this... nothing happens.

I copy my compiled binary to the right place, and run it. I leave it running, and switch back to VS. Go to Debug → Attach to process… and select my running program. VS clearly goes into debug mode, but... I can't *see* anything. The call stack is blank, it won't tell me what code is running... I can't *do* anything!

(Again: There's no error message. It seems to have connected just fine. It's just that nothing *happens*.)

Clearly a debugger that won't let you do anything is utterly pointless, so this obviously isn't what's supposed to happen. How do I make it so VS will actually show me what's running, let me poke variables, step through stuff, etc. You know, *debug stuff*?

(Again, this is unmanaged C++ code compiled to native machine code.)

Comment: You need to set a break point or pause the execution of the program manually.

Comment: @SimonKraemer You can't just get VS to tell you what function it's reached?

Comment: You can press the "Break All" button to break into a running process that you are attached to. It looks like a pause button.

Comment: @Ralara Works great! Can you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Break All" button will break into a running process that you are attached to. It's the one that looks like a pause button.